# How to use React canary in plain HTML? Or, how can I include react-dom/client?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cdn

So for reasons that I'm not going to explain, I'm developing a React application without bundlers (e.g., webpack). So basically I just include React and ReactDOM in a couple of `<script>` tags in my `index.html`, fetching those scripts from a CDN, for example:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js
```

So far so good, but now I decided to try and experiment with [`Suspense`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense) and [`use`](https://react.dev/reference/react/use). The latter being a canary-only feature.

The first issue I faced is how to find the latest canary build, I assume it can be found in the [CHANGELOG-canary.md](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG-canary.md) file. Is this reliable?

Then I just updated the above URLs in my application, using the `18.3.0-canary-546178f91-20231005` version. But now I get two errors:

- `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unstable_cancelCallback')`;
- `TypeError: ReactDOM.createRoot is not a function`.

It seems that, *now*, `createRoot` has been moved in `react-dom/client`. But what does it mean in terms of CDNs? It seems I cannot find it anywhere...

Comment: Did you check this? https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react and https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-dom?

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar links to cdnjs are literally in the question body. Where's the _client_ part? And how can it be included in the HTML?

Comment: I added an example in the answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why the error is occurring in that release. But you can try to get the latest canary release to test it out.

**Finding the CDN links:**

CDN links are available on [cdn.js](https://cdnjs.com/).

React CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react

React DOM CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-dom

**Finding the latest canary release**

1. Go to versions tab in [react npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react?activeTab=versions)
2. Copy the latest canary release that you want and search that in cdn.js.
3. Copy the script tags and paste them into your project.

Alternatively, if you have `npm` available, you can:

```
npm view react dist-tags.canary
```

Also, if you are using npm and want to always update to the latest canary release you can run the following command. [Reference](https://react.dev/community/versioning-policy#canary-channel)

```
npm update react@canary react-dom@canary
```

or

```
yarn upgrade react@canary react-dom@canary
```

**Example**

One example of using it is as follows (taken from [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/use#streaming-data-from-server-to-client)):

```js
const {useState, use, Suspense} = React;

function fetchMessage() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "⚛️"));
}

function Message({ messagePromise }) {
  const messageContent = use(messagePromise);
  return <p>Here is the message: {messageContent}</p>;
}

function MessageContainer({ messagePromise }) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>⌛Downloading message...</p>}>
      <Message messagePromise={messagePromise} />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [messagePromise, setMessagePromise] = useState(null);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  function download() {
    setMessagePromise(fetchMessage());
    setShow(true);
  }

  if (show) {
    return <MessageContainer messagePromise={messagePromise} />;
  } else {
    return <button onClick={download}>Download message</button>;
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.0-canary-cb2439624-20231219/umd/react.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-DyF9mlaay3VPTJNySTYIgb2dsv0NXOcY/IRkCFm/1J/w4B3oOXA6LGwS04cgMFHcSB5b7WXqbOsBaAsWsvcj8g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.0-canary-cb2439624-20231219/umd/react-dom.development.min.js" integrity="sha512-kkJ9iTzcc6cLoFeK+Kp13xvLpIa/+if1NSX7R1ThvHgw6VccDudy8qb5FGyismOvnaGfI604s7ZD6Rzu4Awpng==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: It works, but those are older versions from 2022-10-25, the latest canary (the one in the OP), doesn't.

Comment: Updated to latest that i can find 20231219 @cYrus

Comment: Nice! So it's just that one particular version that doesn't work... do you have any idea why? Also is the latest version tracked somewhere or my best bet is to just walk through all the (unordered) list and find the latest?

Comment: Yeah, I think that seems to be a problem with that specific release. You can track the latest releases on [react npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react?activeTab=versions) versions tab. Copy the latest version and paste in cdnjs search.

Comment: Awesome, do you mind rewriting the answer to address all that? After all the question was about how to find the latest canary and how to include it in a plain HTML.

Comment: Done. Do let me know if anything else is missing.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much, that was driving me insane! (I'll grant you the bounty as soon as SO will let me.)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @cYrus. I also added another command to always update to the latest canary version.

Comment: npm update not working

Comment: Can you tell about the error? @ИгорТашевски

Comment: @BhaveshParvatkar 

npm ERR! code EUPDATEARGS
npm ERR! Update arguments must only contain package names, eg:
npm ERR!     npm update react

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/igor/.npm/_logs/2024-02-28T15_38_29_907Z-debug-0.log

Comment: It works with yarn. Not sure what's wrong with npm. Will check that.